# Should we sell our current primary residence to payoff a rental we also own in favor of no mortgages?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, financing

- Townhouse: About 10 years ago we bought a nice townhouse for about 300K.
- Single family: About 4 years ago we decided to buy a single family house for about 400K and we kept the townhouse and it is a rental right now.

Townhouse payoff today is around 200K and estimated value is around 475K
Single family payoff today is 350K and estimated value is around 600K

We have decided to look into selling our single family and use the equity to payoff the townhouse which would mean to downsize and move back to our townhouse at the end of the townhouse's agreement.

While it looks and sounds nice to go from two mortgages to no mortgages, we don't know if this is the right move down the road. And what triggered this idea is the crazy high prices of homes today.

Please advise or comment!

Country: USA

Comment: Please specify the country, because there may be tax issues that have to be considered.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep updated, and you are right it wouldn't be wise to neglect capital gains if applicable, and any other tax implications.

Comment: I think that depends a lot on the detailed numbers: mortgage rates and rental income. If the townhouse is nicely profitable, you can use that money to pay of your  mortgage on the single family home faster. If you have really low mortgage rates, you may want to hold on to these (since they are going up fast)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a wonderful blessing to own a home free and clear, and it gives you great downside protection.  However, for many, it is a source of great pride and a goal to "have others pay your mortgage" in the form of owning real estate and renting to others.

The first question you need to answer is:  Do you like being a landlord?  Even with good tenants, being a landlord is real work and a bit of a headache.  In many cases one is better off concentrating on their primary career then holding a "side job" as a landlord.  If you answer "no" to this question, then the answer is simple.  You should sell one of the properties.

The second question is do you like the town house or single family home better?  My own prejudice would say the single family home would be a much better option, but not everyone would agree and your circumstances would be very different.  Also consider future family planning.  Wanting to have more children might help you make the choice.  So once you find the one you like least, sell that one.

Even if you end up selling the townhouse, you will only owe about 200K on the single family home (after closing costs) which can be paid off in a reasonable amount of time if you concentrate on it.

I think it is worthwhile to make the right choice as it is very expensive to transact real estate.  I traded homes about a year ago, and estimated costs at about 50K.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I know there is many assumptions but I think this could be useful to other people in case they are in a similar situation. At the end of the day every case is very different and depends on the person/family's goals and preferences. Thanks again.

Comment: @tivo I think it is important to have a counter voice to the mantra that everyone should be a landlord.  It takes skill and effort and is not for everyone.

Comment: @PeteB. But having that voice might crash the housing market, so we shouldn't.